# Components.classes gives "Error: Permission denied to access property 'classes'"

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize my DOM to an XML file using the method outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML).

However, the line

```
var oFOStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
```

results in the error

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'classes'
```

using Firebug on Mozilla Firefox 20.0.  I could be that

```
mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream
```

is a bad link.  However, when I tried

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");     
var oFOStream = new FileUtils.File(".");
```

I got the message

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'utils'
```

and

```
resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm
```

is a legitimate link.

Is there a better way to serialize the DOM, or preferably a subtree therein, to an XML file?

Answer (score 1):

The method you use is only nescesarry when "From within a JS XPCOM component (or a JS module), new XMLSerializer() is not available."

You can try to use:

```
var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
var sXML = oSerializer.serializeToString(doc);
```

first to serialize it to a string.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) at chapter 2.